how to select N distinct items from M conflict items with different weight? #algorithm A-Res
A-RES
A-RES calls for the selection of m distinct random items out of a population of size n, each item with weight.
but my case is:
a huge stream of input(some item maybe conflict many times with different weight)
ex (item ID: weight) : a:10, b:5, ... a: 20... b:20, c:30...
select m distinct item from this population. "a" weight should be sum all a's weight.
my question : is there any algorithm can do this case ?
my question : is there any algorithm can do this case ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
